# Java fx Application crash automatically after some time

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, ubuntu, javafx-8

I have developed javaFx application which crashed after some  times during working.Meanwhile  switching between the  registered users of application i am using custom dialog boxes for username and password.As soon as pop up opens for password application goes crashed.Here i am getting the error message.I am using ubntu 14.0.

```
  #
      # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
      #
      #  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f205619792e, pid=8902, tid=139775151732480
      #
      # JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_45-b14) (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
      # Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.45-b02 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
      # Problematic frame:
      # V  [libjvm.so+0x6c492e]  jni_invoke_nonstatic(JNIEnv_*, JavaValue*, _jobject*, JNICallType, _jmethodID*, JNI_ArgumentPusher*, Thread*)+0xa1e
      #
      # Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
      #
      # If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
      #   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
 #
```

I had already updated my java version from 1.8.0_45 to 1.8.0_71.But problems remains same.
  Here is the code for pop up which one i am using for user's password.

```
                     GridPane grid = new GridPane();
                     final PasswordField passwordPasswordField = new PasswordField();
                     final Dialog dlg = new Dialog(null, "Open User's Profile");
                     grid.add(passwordPasswordField, 1, 2);
                     dlg.setContent(grid);
                     dlg.show();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about that particular error, but you could try [upgrading to 8u71](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).  There's been a bunch of fixes since the version you're using (8u45).